# send text as a file to the backend with other values

Tags: angular, typescript, https

I am taking a text from a text field and and need to save the text with the `backend` **and the backend not saving that data as a text but as a file** so I need to send the text in as a file to the backend

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-x-page',
    templateUrl: './x-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./x-page.component.scss']
})
export class XPageComponent{
    private xObj = {
        id: "ffff-ffff-ffff",
        title: "xxxxxx"
    }
    public xForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      file: new FormControl(''),
    })

    constructor(private XService: XService) { }

    public onSubmit(){
        this.xForm.get('file').setValue({
            filename: '_.md',
            type: 'text/plain',
            value: this.xForm.get('file').value
        });

        this.XService.updateX(
            this.xObj.id, 
            this.xObj.title, 
            this.xForm.value
        ).subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
    }


/* ... [XService] the updateX function ... */
public updateX(id: string, title: string, updateData){
    const url:string = `${this.appConfig.backendRoot}/X/${id}/${title}/`;
    return this.putDataToURL(url, updateData);
  }


/* .. [XService] pubDataToURL function ...*/
public putDataToURL<T>(url: string, data: any){
    /**
     * sending put request with the given data
     * to the given URL
     */
    return this.http.put(url, data, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-CSRFToken', 
      this.userService.getCSRFToken())
    }).pipe(
          catchError(this.errorLogger(url))
    );
  }
```

when I send it I recv unsupported media type `415`

Comment: Do you control the backend?

Comment: yes is written in `python` (django)

Comment: Why not handle file creation on the backend?

Comment: it is messy and I want to keep the option for the user to upload a new file or edit the current one

Comment: and I dont want the backend to handle things that I can do in the frontend so the backend stay fast

Comment: Mmhmm. I'm not sure those are real arguments, but hey, up to you. Your 415 error is coming from somewhere in your Python code, surely you can find where?

Comment: is the way that I am sending the text is correct?

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a `Blob` if you really need to create the file in the front end…I still reckon it's not a great idea though. Even just from a security standpoint, it's easier to sanitize the text on the backend before saving…